# how to pythonanywhere database connections?

Tags: mysql, pythonanywhere

I am currently deploying a web application on PythonAnywhere. I cloned the code from GitHub and transferred it to the PythonAnywhere console. I have also set up the Django environment and successfully installed Django using "pip install django". I have installed other necessary modules as well. The deployed web interface is working fine, but I'm encountering an error stating that the MySQL connection is not established. I have checked the MySQL connection and also verified the database settings in the config.py file, but I'm unable to identify the problem and resolve it. Please help me.

my settions.py databases

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "name",
        "USER": "root",
        "PASSWORD": "password",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "3306",
    }
}
```

When I run the command "python manage.py migrate" on PythonAnywhere, I encounter the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)")
```

Comment: this error may be when you have different port or you may need to insure that you are using the correct MySQL server configuration as well so check if different then use that port with 127.0.0.1:Port

Answer (score 2):

In PythonAnywhere you should use:

```
...
'NAME':  '<your_pythonanywhere_username>$<database_name>',
'USER': '<your_pythonanywhere_username>',
'PASSWORD': '<mysql_password>',
'HOST': '<mysql_hostname>',
...
```

where:

`database_name` and `mysql_hostname` are listed on the *Databases* page -- if you haven't created a database there, you should do it first (you'd specify the `mysql_password` there, too).

Alternatively, if you'd like to use an externally hosted database, you need to use a paid account.